# How can I ask Emacs to use different tags for different source files?

Tags: emacs, ctags

If I've got two different projects open in Emacs — `proj1/foo.c` and `proj2/bar.py` — how can I ask Emacs to use `proj1/TAGS` when looking up tags for files under `proj1`, and `proj2/TAGS` when looking up tags for files under `proj2`?

Comment: Related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29571/automatically-locate-use-the-right-etags-file-for-each-project

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest DIY approach is [directory-local variables](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables).

```
$ cat proj1/.dir-locals.el
((nil . ((tags-file-name . "~/projects/proj1/TAGS"))))

$ cat proj2/.dir-locals.el
((nil . ((tags-file-name . "~/projects/proj2/TAGS"))))
```

If Emacs asks you whether to "Keep current list of tags tables also?" you should reply 'no' to avoid mixing the tables within a given project. (It shouldn't ask you this frequently, and answering 'no' won't cause Emacs to forget which TAGS to use for the files from the other project.)

Comment: Hrm… is there any way to do this automatically? It seems kind of annoying to add one of these each time I start on a new project (or clone an open source project, or whatever)

Comment: There are certainly ways to do it automatically. I rather thought someone might have added one by now, but I'll try to remember to update this answer later with the approach I use. I do wonder whether you would be more interested in one of the more fully-featured 'project' oriented libraries out there, though? I think some of them would include not only this functionality, but also other beneficial defaults (a find-file-in-project command being a popular example).

Comment: Ohh, that would be even better.

Comment: I don't really have comparative knowledge of the available options, but I'll point you at [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) which is actively developed/maintained, and may well provide everything you're looking for.

Comment: `projectile-find-tag` bound by default to `C-c p j` (or `j` after your configured projectile prefix binding) looks like the function to use for your original query.